# Видеофон на Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Помогите пожалуйста поставить видео фон, растянутый на всю страницу сайта на drupal 7!?!?!

Comment: Попробуйте на сайте https://www.drupal.org в поиске ввести `video background`. Сдаётся мне, вы найдете один-другой модуль с нужным вам функционалом.